# EpiServer content synchronization

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, episerver

I just started working with EPiServer (Sitecore before) and looking for a way how to synchronize content between environments automatically (developer-developer and developer-QA env).

We have our QA environment on an azure virtual machine and need to synchronize content during CI/CD.
EPiServer DXC Service doesn't meet the requirements because we are not working on a web app service.

Any ideas? Is there any already existing way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Automatic synchronization between environments has [more-or-less] gone away within the Episerver platform. The old way of doing this was using [mirroring](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Deployment/mirroring/), but that's not available in the DXP, and is eventually being removed from the platform in favor of other strategies:

1. For moving bulk data (content items, content types, categories, visitor groups, etc.) between different environments, without touching code or the database, use the "Import Data" and "Export Data" tools within Admin mode. More information here: http://webhelp.episerver.com/latest/en/cms-admin/exporting-importing-data.htm
2. For bigger bulk migrations of data between environments, typically a database backup and restore is done between environments. Obviously, this is a bit more risky when involving a production environment.
3. If the content (or a content type change) is required as part of a deployment, you can build a content migration step. More information here: https://www.gulla.net/en/blog/renaming-an-episerver-page-property-using-a-migration-step/ and https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Content/Refactoring-content-type-classes/
4. If you are simply wanting to move authored content from a staging environment to production, it's suggested to create all content in production and use Episerver's Projects feature. More information here: https://webhelp.episerver.com/latest/en/cms-edit/projects.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure DevOps for CI/CD you might want to look into Epinova DXP Extension to Azure DevOps - that uses the Episerver deployment API but makes this easier to set up your pipelines. See https://www.epinova.no/en/folg-med/blog/2020/episerver-dxp-content-harmonization-with-epinova-dxp-deployment/ for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the Deployment API. There might be something in there for you. https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/digital-experience-platform/deploying/episerver-digital-experience-cloud-deployment-api/

Comment: Seems they're on Azure but not on DXP.